# Substituting a two term expression with two rule on one variable with which each of the rules simplify one of the terms

Tags: simplifying-expressions, rule

I have two expressions as follows:

```
r (Sin[t]+Cos[t])
```

and the rules for simplification are:

```
{x == b + x Cos[t], y == r Sin[t]}
```

How can I get the following result and eliminate `r` without using `Simplify`.

```
x-b+y
```

This is a very simple example and for the real case I do not want the expression to be fully simplifed.

Comment: This site does not cater to questions related to Wolfram Alpha. Please format your code accordingly and present a **minimal** working example that replicates your problem.

Comment: My problem is about Wolfram Mathematica. I tried to express my problem as simple as I could. @Syed

Comment: What are `Sine` and `cos`? Did you mean `Sin` and `Cos`?

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited the problem. @RohitNamjoshi

Comment: You did not fix the `Sine`.

Comment: I do not understand your mentioned problem. @RohitNamjoshi

Comment: Please read your question `y == r Sine[t]`. What is `Sine`?

Comment: Aha, got it! Sorry...Thank you@RohitNamjoshi

Comment: (Note correction to `x` equation) `expr = {e1 - r (Sin[t] + Cos[t]), x - (b + r Cos[t]), y - r Sin[t]};I Quiet[e1 /. First[Solve[Eliminate[expr == 0, {r, t}], e1]]]

Out[1343]= -b + x + y`